# Cannot render a Scene in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to learn OpenGL via a tutorial in youtube called *Graphics Programming with OpenGL and Qt*. I did everything exactly according to this tutorial but I cant render my triangle. Here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "GlWindow.h"

void GlWindow::initializeGL(){
    glewInit();

    GLfloat verts[] = {
        0.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f

    };

    GLuint myBufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &myBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);

}

void GlWindow::paintGL(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

and here is my GLWindow.h code:

```
#ifndef GLWINDOW_H
#define GLWINDOW_H
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>

class GlWindow : public QGLWidget{
public:

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
};

#endif // GLWINDOW_H
```

And my main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <GlWindow.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    GlWindow glWindow;
    glWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

But the output is just a black window. If I also use `glClearColor(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);`
 I will have a red window. But I don't know why my triangle is not shown.

**Edit:** Im using ubuntu 15 and when I run `glx info | grep version` I get this:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.5.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.5.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

Comment: Are we talking OpenGL >= 2? Where's your shader program?

Comment: @peppe I think my OpenGL version is OpenGL version string: 3.0. The tutorial that I'm following does not use any shaders.

Comment: Qt already handles OpenGL function loading. And QGLWidget is deprecated. Use QOpenGLWidget instead.

Comment: @Poriferous Thank u, Im using QOpenGLWidget now but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the vertex coordinates:

```
   GLfloat verts[] = {
        0.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f
```

Change them for example to:

```
   GLfloat verts[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f
```

and if the other code is correct you will see a triangle in the bottom left corner.

Comment: I still have the problem, I changed the coordinates but I still got a black window

Comment: There could be a lot of other problems. Depending on which OpenGL version you are using you have to specify a shader program and make use of vertex arrays. Furthermore its not a good practice to use the sizeof operator in this way. Instead especially in testing you should use a constant. `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);` Maybe you should begin learning with OpenGL version 1.1, there you don't have to use shader programs.